# New gas link from Spain to Germany - Could it result in higher gas bills for Spaniards?

Tags: energy-economics

***The Question***
There seem to be plans now to connect the gas from Spain to Germany, Could it result in higher gas bills for Spaniards ?

I wonder if it will also involve increasing the gas pressure ( or speed ) to cater for the massive increase in customers.  If it is possible to increase the gas pressure ( or speed ), then could that increase in gas pressure ( or speed ) be equal to ( = ) the amount of additional customers.

If the gas pressure ( or speed ) can not be increased, then you would think that the same amount of gas shared between much much more customers would result in higher gas bills for Spaniards.

( Also, by sharing that gas link, could any other factors result in higher gas bills for Spaniards  )

Comment: After the first paragraph, this seems to be an engineering question?

Comment: You are asking whether they will drill more gas in Spain to make up for the extra gas flowing to Germany.